# How would I use this filter to change the output of the date format to "Twitter time"?

Tags: php, date, twitter

I'm using a plugin called [Latest Tweet Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/) to display the latest tweet. The tweet date gets displayed by the month and day (Mar 22). However, I want it to be in "Twitter time" meaning words like "3 days ago, 1 hour ago, etc.".

I asked the developer of the plugin at the WordPress forums and he said that I need to "use the `latest_tweets_render_date` filter to perform my own relative date representation."

The filter in question is here under the "Custom HTML" section (also quoted below): https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/other_notes/#Theming

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_date', function( $created_at ){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s O Y', $created_at );
    return $date->format('d M h:ia'); }, 10 , 1 );
```

However, I am new to PHP and unable to understand what exactly needs to be written in order for "Twitter time" to work. Can somebody please show me the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has a core function [`human_time_diff`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff) that does what you want, using it with the filter you provide you have someting like so:

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_date', function( $created_at ){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s O Y', $created_at ); 
    return sprintf( '%s ' . __( 'ago' ), human_time_diff( $date->format('U') ) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, G.M. However, I just tried this and latest tweet date is now displaying as "44 years". Any idea what could be setting it back so far?

Comment: I just tried deactivating all of my other plugins and it still shows as "44 years ago" so I'm guessing the problem can be narrowed down to the plugin using a different format than the one documented. Is this something only the plugin author can help me with?

Comment: @Desi just noticed there was an error in my code, sorry. Try now.